# CS GO not launch

Tags: games, steam, opengl

Hi i have the next problem:

when i try to enter in CS-Go the game is not launching and in the terminal i have the next error

```
chdir "/media/*/69B95971153C7E09/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive"
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/*/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/*/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/*/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/*/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
/media/*/69B95971153C7E09/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo.exe: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

i try even to reinstall ubuntu

Comment: The `*` in `/media/*/69B95971153C7E09/...` or `/home/*/.local/...` looks suspicious, and the last line might mean that your system tries to interpret a Windows executable as a shell script. What hardware are you trying to use? How exactly did you install the software? Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification.

Comment: the ```*``` is puted by me just to have that empty, i use steam from the site

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Editing or re-typing the output might introduce or hide errors. If you think your username is sensitive information, replace it consistently with something that would be a valid name. You did not answer the question about your hardware. Add links to the instructions and download pages and specify what files exactly you downloaded. The answer "i use steam from the site" is not sufficient to allow us to check if you might have made a mistake.